# NodeJS: Pass array and display the values on html page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have written below code to read values from mongodb using mongoose and store it in array:

```
app.get('/StudentQuestionsPage',function(req,res){
    var allQuestionsArray = studentQuestions.find();
    var questions = [];
    allQuestionsArray.exec(function(err,questions){
        if(err)
            return cosole.log(err);
        questions.forEach(function(question){       
            var elem = new Object();
            elem["id"] = question.id;
            elem["quesStatement"] = question.quesStatement;
            elem["optionA"]=question.optionA;
            elem["optionB"]=question.optionB;
            elem["optionC"]=question.optionC;
            elem["optionD"]=question.optionD;

            questions.push(elem);
            console.log(elem)
        });
    }); 
    res.render(__dirname + '/StudentQuestionsPage.html',{questions:questions});
});
```

I have to pass this array of questions to an html file and then I have to show the content on HTML.

I have written below code to show array values on HTML but it does not show anything. "`console.log(elem)`" can print values on console.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Online Examination Portal</title>
        <h1>Questions</h1>
    </head> 
    <body>
        <div>   
        <form>
            <h2>Questions</h2>
                <ul>
                    <% questions.forEach(function(question) { %>
                    <li>Number: <%= question.id %> <br/> Text: <%= question.quesStatement %></li>
                    <% }); %>
                </ul>
        </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please let me know how can I pass the values from nodejs and retrieve and show it on html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, rename your `questions` array to `allQuestions` or whatever you want exept `questions`. Your `.exec's` success function's parameter name is same as the array. So, it will override the array variable.
Since `allQuestionsArray.exec` is an `async` function you should pass the `allQuestions` array from success function. Rewrite your code as following...

```
app.get('/StudentQuestionsPage',function(req,res){
var allQuestionsArray = studentQuestions.find();
var allQuestions = [];
allQuestionsArray.exec(function(err,questions){
    if(err)
        return console.log(err);
    questions.forEach(function(question){       
        var elem = new Object();
        elem["id"] = question.id;
        elem["quesStatement"] = question.quesStatement;
        elem["optionA"]=question.optionA;
        elem["optionB"]=question.optionB;
        elem["optionC"]=question.optionC;
        elem["optionD"]=question.optionD;

        allQuestions.push(elem);
        console.log(elem)
    });
    res.render(__dirname + '/StudentQuestionsPage.html',{questions:allQuestions});
  }); 
});
```

Comment: @Abhinav have you tried the solution? Is there any issue ?

Comment: Yes, I tried. But it does not display anything on HTML.

Comment: @Abhinav I think you have some problems with the HTML. Please, review it.

Comment: is you html page loading correctly? is data loading correctly? please check